# Why is Python's re module not working in this method?

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm having trouble creating an instance of a class using Python's re module. Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Loop over each line of many data files.
2. If a line matches the format of a record, then create an instance of the Record class with the record's two values as attributes.

I expect the following code fragment to print the string of five capital letters captured by the `re` module in the `terminal()` method for the Record class, but clearly I'm misunderstanding something. The actual output follows below the code.

```
    class SrcFile:
       def __init__(self, which):
          self.name = which       

    class Record(SrcFile):       
       def terminal(self):
          recordline = re.compile(r"^([A-Z]{5})\s{3}")
          if recordline.match(self):
             m = recordline.match(self)
             return m.group(1)

    for f in files:
       file = SrcFile(f)
       for l in f:
          record = Record(f)
          print(record.terminal())
```

Again, I expect to see a string of five capital letters for each record line, but what I actually get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./next.py", line 78, in <module>
    print(record.terminal())
  File "./next.py", line 63, in terminal
    if recordline.match(self):
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

It would also be helpful if someone could explain why, in the code

```
for f in files:
   file = SrcFile(f)
   for l in f:
      record = Record(f)
```

it is apparently incorrect to use `record = Record(file)`. I discovered this by trial and error, as I couldn't access the methods of the SrcFile class for a file using record.method() with the incorrect code, but I don't understand why.

I'm certain that my inexperience with programming in general and Python in particular is rather obvious. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean to write

```
if recordline.match(self.name):
```

rather than

```
if recordline.match(self):
```

When you call `re.match`, you're supposed to do so with a string. `self` is not a string, but rather a `Record` object, while `self.name` is the string set in the line

```
          self.name = which
```

There are two more basic problems that relate to your other question.

1. You're never using the line itself, `l`, which is the whole reason you're iterating through the file. Perhaps you meant to write `Record(l)`.
2. Why does the Record class inherit the `SourceFile` object (with the code `class Record(SourceFile)`?) You should read more carefully about [inheritance](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance): inheritance is used to share methods and properties between multiple objects, and it doesn't really apply to this code.

Comment: Plus he's not using the `SrcFile` instance called `file`.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, Thanks for pointing out my mistakes; it's been a day full of them!

Comment: Everyone starts as a beginner!